# Why do I encounter an error on a simple matrix function

Tags: c

I don't understand why my program crashes every time I finish reading and my showing function comes....
The error says read access violation

```
void read(int **m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=", i, j);
            scanf("%d", (m + i * n + j));
        }
}

void show(int **m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(m + i * n + j));//where the error occurs
            printf("\n");
        }
}

int main()
{
    int **m;
    int opt,n;
    printf("Introduceti nr de linii si coloane:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    m= (int*)malloc(n*n * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Ask yourself: how is `read` supposed to know `m` is a 2D array and not an array of pointers?

Comment: An `int **` is not a `int[][]`.

Comment: You need to check compiler warnings about incompatible types.

Comment: `j <= n` in a loop condition is more often an off by one error than correct code.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment, your primary issue is you allocate storage for `n * n` pointers, but then fail to allocate any storage for the `int` values. When working with pointers and/or allocating storage dynamically, you should always be able to answer *"To what valid storage do each of my pointers point?"*. If you can't you have no idea what address you are attempting to use.

(**note:** you only need to allocate `n` pointers -- one for each row)

As @RetiredNinja also points out, you have an *Off-By-One* error in `for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)` which attempts to read the address for `n + 1` integer values per row.

Since you have allocated `n * n` pointers, you now need to allocate storage for `n` integers assigning the address for each new valid block of memory to each of your pointers in turn. Additionally, in `read()` since your read with `scanf()` or allocation with `malloc()` can fail, you must provide a return type for the `read()` function that can indicate success or failure. Making the return type `int` and returning `1` on success or `0` on failure is fine.

(**note:** since `read()` conflicts with an existing syscall name, you should rename your `read()` function, e.g. `mtrxread()` or the like)

Putting that altogether, you can do something like:

```c
/* type must be capable of indicating success/failure */
int mtrxread (int **m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* guard each block with {...} */
        
        /* allocate n int / validate EVERY allocation */
        if (!(m[i] = malloc (n * sizeof *m[i]))) {
            perror ("malloc-m[i]");
            return 1;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            
            if (scanf ("%d", &m[i][j]) != 1) {  /* validate EVERY input */
                fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 1;
}
```

(**note:** In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714))

(also fix the `<=` making it `<` in `show()`)

In `main()`, you need to validate EVERY input and EVERY allocation - just as you do everywhere else. You also need to validate whether `mtrxread()` succeeds or fails. Putting that together, you can do:

```c
int main (void) {
    
    int **m;    /* NOT an array, a pointer-to-pointer-to int */
    int n;
    
    fputs ("Introduceti nr de linii si coloane: ", stdout);
    
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { /* validate EVERY input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* validate EVERY allocation */
    if (!(m = malloc (n * sizeof *m))) {
        perror ("malloc-m");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (!mtrxread (m, n)) {   /* validate read of elements */
        return 1;
    }
    
    show (m, n);              /* show the matrix */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free (m[i]);          /* free int storage */
    }
    
    free (m);                 /* free pointers */
}
```

(**note:** the additional information provided by comments in the code)

The complete code could be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* type must be capable of indicating success/failure */
int mtrxread (int **m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* guard each block with {...} */
        
        /* allocate n int / validate EVERY allocation */
        if (!(m[i] = malloc (n * sizeof *m[i]))) {
            perror ("malloc-m[i]");
            return 1;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            
            if (scanf ("%d", &m[i][j]) != 1) {  /* validate EVERY input */
                fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 1;
}

void show (int **m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", m[i][j]);//where the error occurs
        }
        putchar ('\n');   /* you putchar() a single character */
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    int **m;    /* NOT an array, a pointer-to-pointer-to int */
    int n;
    
    fputs ("Introduceti nr de linii si coloane: ", stdout);
    
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { /* validate EVERY input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* validate EVERY allocation */
    if (!(m = malloc (n * sizeof *m))) {
        perror ("malloc-m");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (!mtrxread (m, n)) {   /* validate read of elements */
        return 1;
    }
    
    show (m, n);              /* show the matrix */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free (m[i]);          /* free int storage */
    }
    
    free (m);                 /* free pointers */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptr2ptr2int-allocate
Introduceti nr de linii si coloane: 3
a[0][0] = 1
a[0][1] = 2
a[0][2] = 3
a[1][0] = 4
a[1][1] = 5
a[1][2] = 6
a[2][0] = 7
a[2][1] = 8
a[2][2] = 9
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ptr2ptr2int-allocate
==5081== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5081== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5081== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5081== Command: ./bin/ptr2ptr2int-allocate
==5081==
Introduceti nr de linii si coloane: 3
a[0][0] = 1
a[0][1] = 2
a[0][2] = 3
a[1][0] = 4
a[1][1] = 5
a[1][2] = 6
a[2][0] = 7
a[2][1] = 8
a[2][2] = 9
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
==5081==
==5081== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5081==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5081==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 2,156 bytes allocated
==5081==
==5081== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5081==
==5081== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==5081== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

---

**Option For Single-Allocation/Single-Free with Pointer to VLA**

C provides a, now optional, feature called a *Variable Length Array*, that in your case can provide a single-allocation/single-free. While this feature was made optional in C11, it will remain widely supported for some time. By using a *pointer-to-VLA-of* `int[n]`, you can make a single call to `malloc()` in `main()` to allocate all storage required. The changes required are:

```c
int main (void) {
    
    int n;
    
    fputs ("Introduceti nr de linii si coloane: ", stdout);
    
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { /* validate EVERY input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    int (*m)[n];    /* pointer to VLA of n int */
    
    /* validate EVERY allocation */
    if (!(m = malloc (n * sizeof *m))) {
        perror ("malloc-m");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (!mtrxread (n, m)) {   /* validate read of elements */
        return 1;
    }
    
    show (n, m);              /* show the matrix */
    
    free (m);                 /* free allocated memory */
}
```

The order of your parameters for each function will need to change so the size `n` is known before the pointer to VLA is provided. For example `mtrxread()` would reduce to:

```c
/* type must be capable of indicating success/failure */
int mtrxread (int n, int (*m)[n])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* guard each block with {...} */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            
            if (scanf ("%d", &m[i][j]) != 1) {  /* validate EVERY input */
                fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 1;
}
```

(change the order for `show()` in like manner)

Now all memory is allocated at once and requires only a single call to `free()`. Quite convenient, but with the caveat of the VLA now having optional support from compilers.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Aside: concerning `sizeof *m[i]`, I use to do likewise, yet I find now greater clarity with `sizeof m[i][0]`.  IAC, a _style_ issue.

Comment: The older my eyes get, the more attractive the `[0]` looks compared to the `*`. Indirection, by any other name, would it still smell as sweet?

Comment: It is the Left-to-right of `[]` that I find easier than Right-to-left of `*`even thought `sizeof` is `R-L`.